# text not centering inside div

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="carousel-item-top">
    <img class="img-responsive" alt="a" src="carousel/crsl-img-1.png">
    <div class="carousel-item-top-hover">
        <div class="buttons">
            <a class="button btn" href="#">view larger</a>
            <a class="button btn" href="#">more details</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the html for this piece of code. The text in the button btn classes i want centered, but for some reason it doesn't respond to text-align: center

```
.carousel-item-top {
    position: relative;
}

.carousel-item-top-hover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #219fd1;
    opacity: 0;
}

.carousel-item-top-hover .buttons {
    width: 100%;
    top: 45%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
}

.carousel-item-top-hover .buttons .button {
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    padding: 6px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 4px;
}

.carousel-item-top-hover .buttons .button:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And this is the css concerning the rebel element and its relevant neoighbors. Anyone has any ideea as to why it doesn't work?

Comment: What is the CSS for the `btn` class?

Comment: It's bootstrap. Adding it had no effect so you can consider it not present

Answer (score 0):

A-ha! It seems it had a text-indent from somewhere, so i set it as none in the button class.